# What is the meaning of 拝承致します?

Tags: words, formality

According to the site [RomanjiDesu](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E6%8B%9D%E6%89%BF.html):

> 拝承 means hearing; understanding; learning; being informed

Another definition from [goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/173799/meaning/m0u/):

> 聞くこと、承知することをへりくだっていう語。謹んで承ること。「お申し越しの御趣旨拝承いたしました」

The latter definition is almost the same as the first definition. But it has an example. I tried to translate the example using google translate to try to understand how 拝承 is translated in English when incorporated in a complete sentence.

Below is the Google Translate translation:

> 「お申し越しの御趣旨拝承いたしました」= I wish you the intention of the application.

> お申し越しの御趣旨 = Purpose of application

Honestly, I'm not confident with my own translation. But my own translation is "I was informed of the purpose of the translation."

Is my understanding correct?

Can you give me advice on how to interpret the word 拝承 when used in a sentence?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the clerical error.
My translation is:  "I was informed of the purpose of the application."

Also below is the links for the 2 definition:
http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E6%8B%9D%E6%89%BF.html

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/173799/meaning/m0u/

Comment: There is no word "application" in any of the Japanese examples. The definitions of 拝承, which you included, are clear and unequivocal. What is the problem to solve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, 拝承致しました is rarer (and thus probably politer) than 承知致しました/了解致しました, which is politer than 分かりました. The basic meaning is the same — "we heard" or "okay".

> お申し越しの御趣旨拝承いたしました ≒ 連絡の趣旨を了解しました。

Some people use 拝承致しました all the time in business emails, whereas I usually use 了解致しました in business emails. Probably it depends on the culture of each company.

By the way, [お申し越し](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/218514/meaning/m0u/%E7%94%B3%E3%81%97%E8%B6%8A%E3%81%97/) is very rare and Google seems to be confused with this word. I didn't know this word and initially thought お申し越し was a typo for お申し込み ("application"). So Google was somehow reasonable in this case :D